# How to track other's comments on my answers or where I've commented?

Tags: support

Okay, I know it's a total StackExchange n00b question but I cannot figure out how to find the list of question and answers where people have commented on my answers or comments? Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the little envelope to the left of your name, or use this link:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/recent/89

(it should only work for you)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.